# docker run what does "-s" option mean?

Tags: docker

When running docker run it is possibly to specify `-s` option, for example:

```
docker run --name 'mtproto_proxy' --restart unless-stopped -p 1984:1984 -dti dotcypress/mtproxy -s '07123e1f482356c415f684407a3b8723'
```

I have checked official documentation, but there is no information about this option. What does this option mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything after the image name is passed to the container, so that is not a docker flag but an mtproxy flag. It appears to be the proxy secret.

https://github.com/dotcypress/mtproxy#start-proxy

https://github.com/dotcypress/mtproxy/blob/develop/src/main.rs#L40